# Counting Problem on Class of Polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Define a class of polynomials $\mathcal{P}=\lbrace p\in poly_D(\mathbb{R}^n) | p(x_1,x_2,...,x_D)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^Dx_i^{p_i}, 1\leq p_i\leq D, p_i\in\mathbb{Z}^+\rbrace$.

I want to know $|\lbrace p\in\mathcal{P} | deg(p)=k\rbrace |$ for any $1\leq k\leq D$.

I have tried the following argument, and am not sure if this is correct:

For each of the $D$ exponents, we have $D$ to choose from, so we can say $|\mathcal{P}|=D^D$. Then the number of polynomials with degree $D$ is just $D^D-(\# \text{number of polynomials with deg}\neq D)$. The number of polynomials with degree less than $D$ is $(D-1)^D$, since there are $D-1$ exponents to choose from. Therefore, $|\lbrace p\in\mathcal{P} | deg(p)=k\rbrace |=D^D-(D-1)^D$